# SCORM implementation

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile-application, scorm

I have built an e-learning mobile web application with HTML5 using j Query mobile 1.2.0 , 
my question is how to make it comply SCORM standard to communicate any LMS?

I'm currently using SCORM API Wrapper to implement this, but i got struck with http://pipwerks.com/2008/05/08/adding-scorm-code-to-an-html-file/ in Starting the course section...

I got a doubt here that "they implemented SCORM for a simple form, so if i have huge application is that mean i have to implement SCORM for each and every module of my application"

or Is there anyother API or tool to do so?

Kindly help me with the answer...
thanks in advance.

Comment: can someone here give me a basic idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipwerks is great and there's nothing wrong with it. You're probably missing the point.
If you want to convert your web app into a scorm package, you need to:
1. Add an imsmanifest.xml file, which describes in scorm terms, what your app is and what it does etc.
2. Communicate via JS with the LMS (pipwerks wraps everything into convenient methods) to e.g. announce that the user successfully completed your course / used app / etc.
3. Upload all files to LMS server, point your LMS to the imsmanifest.xml and launch from there.